# Get namespace for referenced types using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

I have some code that creates a DOM from my schema:

```
XmlSchemaImporter importer = new XmlSchemaImporter(new XmlSchemas { schema });
CodeNamespace code = new CodeNamespace(targetNamespace);
XmlCodeExporter exporter = new XmlCodeExporter(code);
foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in schema.Elements.Values)
{
    XmlTypeMapping mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(element.QualifiedName);
    exporter.ExportTypeMapping(mapping);
}
```

As I want to create only types from my schema and not from imported schemas, I need to know the `using`-statements I need to create within my output-file. However the namespaces are not preserved within the DOM:

```
<import namespace="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/7.1" schemaLocation="Schema1.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/bfm/1.2" schemaLocation="Schema2.xsd"/>
<element name="UP_Drossel" substitutionGroup="bfm:BP_TechnischeAnlage" type="abw:UP_DrosselType">
</element>
<complexType name="UP_DrosselType">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="bfm:BP_TechnischeAnlageType">
      <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="AblaufInKanten_UL_Rinne" type="adv:InverseReferenceType">
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

When I execute the code, the type of the reference is just `InverseReference` (not `adv:InverseReference`) without any indication about the namespace where this type is defined. So it is impossible to find that type and to add an appropriate `using` within my DOM:

```
var type = code.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().First(x => x.Name == "UP_DrosselType");
var field = type.Members.OfType<CodeMemberField>().First(x => x.Name == "AblaufInKanten_UL_Rinne");
var fieldType = field.Type.BaseType; // only returns InverseReference
```

Comment: In your last line of code, don't you mean ``var fieldType = field.Type.BaseType;``

Comment: This is kind of strange as all the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypereference.basetype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 show the property ``BaseType`` returning the fully qualified name. I'm not familiar with this XML export, so dumb question: the use of ``:`` instead of ``.`` in the type attribute is correct?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins yes, you're correct about the `field`. Which type attribute you refer to? In the schema-definition the syntax using `type=namespace:TypeName` is correct.